# Dynamically set background image not showing in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, background-image

I came across an issue with the background image of a div not showing in Chrome.

A website I'm working on has two image containers sitting on top of another: The one with the lower z-index shows the currently selected image while the one with the higher z-index is used to preview other images when the user hovers over an item in the navigation.

Basically, what is supposed to happen is that every time the mouse cursor is moved from one navigation item to the next, the old preview image is saved as the background of the preview image container and then the actual image in the previewing container is hidden (without it being noticed, since the image is still in the background), swapped for the new image and then faded in. The fade is supposed to happen directly from the old image, which is why I'm setting the old image as a background before.

Now, this works perfectly everywhere but in Google Chrome, where the background image just won't show. The weird thing is, I've used a debugging break to take a closer look and noticed the background image is actually correctly set (meaning it is correctly listed in the CSS of the element at the time), but it is not shown in the browser.

```
var previewDelay; 
$("#cnt-navigation_secondary").find(".txt-navigation_secondary").mouseenter(function(){
    var newImage = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
    var oldImage = $("#img-content-preview").attr("src");
    previewDelay = setTimeout(function(){
        $("#cnt-content-preview").show(); //The previewing container is shown (in case it was hidden before).
        $("#cnt-content-preview").css({"background-image":"url("+oldImage+")"}); //The old image is set as the background of the previewing container
        $("#img-content-preview").hide(); //The image inside the previewing container is hidden. All browsers but Chrome now show still show the same image, as it is in the background, but Chrome doesn't, even though it's visible in the CSS.
        $("#img-content-preview").attr("src", newImage); //The source of the hidden image is set to the new image.
        $("#img-content-preview").fadeIn(400); //The new image is faded in.           
    },100);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    clearTimeout(previewDelay);
});
```

You can see the entire thing in action here: http://www.haasarchitektur.at/index.php?main=1&siteid=403
Try hovering over items in the architecture subnav. In Firefox, for example, the previewing images will fluidly change from one project to another while in Chrome you'll always briefly see the element in the back blink through as the background of the previewing container is not properly set.

I'm kind of at a loss of where this behaviour is coming from, so any help would be greatly appreciated. ; )

Thank you & best regards,
Michael

Comment: It seems to work for me? Although I think there are better ways to achieve this affect with css3 transitions?

Comment: It does? When you hover from one item to the next, you don't see the currently selected project show up briefly in between?

As for the CCS3 transitions: Yeah, but my concern there was IE compatibility. Maybe I'll make it use transitions in compatible browsers only if there's no fix to this. Thanks for the feedback. ; )

Comment: actually no it's not... jQuery doesn't seem to be displaying the cnt-content-preview properly

Comment: @Njord: Your code in `mouseleave` is clashing with your code in `mouseenter`. You clear `previewDelay` at the same time while setting it again and fading in another image. The issue might not be as obvious in other browsers and that may or may not be due to the way other browsers process event orders. Either way, if you can manage to demonstrate the issue in a jsFiddle instead it will enable us to play around with the code, testing different solutions. It also makes your question more useful to future user with similar issues once the site you linked is gone, dead or has changed.

Comment: I would go about doing this a different way, and have your overlaying image fade out once the image behind it was loaded and set with a lower z-index.  similar to this example http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/simple-jquery-image-crossfade/

Comment: @Robert Owen: I'll give it a try this way; thanks everyone who commented so far. ; )

Answer (score 0):

The background image doesn't seem to load because it is quite a large file?  I tried your example setting the background colour to red instead of changing images and it works fine and blocks the original image from being shown.  You may need to work out a way to have the background-image already placed in a div so it is already loaded in the browser..

As you have loaded the images already in your navigation menu, you could tinker with the css so that jquery overlays THIS image until the real image is ready?